# Magento 2: Checkout page getting some error

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am using Magento 2.1.9 when I got checkout page getting this error. if anyone know this error reply me

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/XXX/public_html/XXXX/XXXX/vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Response.php on line 77
```

Comment: did you make some modifications related to checkout?

Comment: actually i applied patch regarding this "Auth.net.md5-2019-02-27-11-48-58.patch" after getting  issue

Comment: that could be the source of error. check your `vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Response.php` on line 77 try to change `:` to `;` and check if that resolves it

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: no but temorary i have to revert back my patch file after checkout working